# How often to COMMIT/EXECUTE in Oracle via Access VBA

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, vba

I'm running the following code in Access / VBA to INSERT INTO an Oracle table (SQL trimmed for effect, but 2 separate statements are needed)

```
Dim mydb            As DAO.Database
Dim myq             As DAO.QueryDef

Set mydb = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
Set myq = mydb.CreateQueryDef("")

With myq
    .SQL = "INSERT INTO tbltrailnew..."
    .Execute 'Execute SQL
    .SQL = "Commit" 'Commit changes to database
    .Execute 'Execute SQL
    .SQL = "INSERT INTO tbltrailnew..."
    .Execute 'Execute SQL
    .SQL = "Commit" 'Commit changes to database
    .Execute 'Execute SQL
    .Close 'Close connection
End With
```

As I'm unfamiliar with Oracle, my question is - am I executing and committing an unnecessary number of times? If so, how can my code be stripped back?

Comment: Whether or not you are committing correctly comes down to how your application is designed. Some reading about database transactions/logical unit of work will give you principles that can be applied whatever the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @StephaneM has a point, here is my take:

Yes, when you are essentially just doing one linked operation, you can commit only once, and usually, that's better than committing multiple times.

A commit just means: make sure everything I just did is permanently written to the database. If the sub you posted above fails halfway through, and you've already committed some inserts, you can't rerun the sub else you will have committed it twice.

If you commit at the end of your sub, you can just run it again if an error occurs when running it.

Removing your first commit is all I'd change.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should commit after every transaction. It doesn't seem from your example that two inserts into one table should be two transactions, so you should have only one commit at the end.

A simple analogy for what should define a transaction is an ATM ash withdrawal. Each button press, right up to the point of cash withdrawal, constitutes one transaction. Once you receive your cash, you would have a COMMIT. If you don't receive your cash, that is a ROLLBACK. Each button press cannot be a transaction, otherwise you could commit at the point of asking for the money and then not receive the cash.

Excessive committing can cause problems, as Oracle has to do a lot of work in the background to write your transaction to disk. If there are large numbers of inserts in a row, such as a data load, we generally commit after about 5000 to 10000. The same for a large number of deletes.

You can also research how to use BULK COLLECT and FORALL / INSERT in order to minimize round-trips between server and client.  This is only if you plan on doing a large amount of DML (insert/update/delete).

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not an Oracle related question. It all has to do with your data. The question you should ask yourself is what should I do if any of the insert fail? Should I perform the other insert? Should I rollback/not perform the other insert?

Just pick the solution that will leave your database in consistent state.